# Get link which associated with a specific category and tag

Tags: categories, tags, query-posts, get-posts

We have 500+ post, 60+ tags, 3 categories. We want to give link on header part which have specific one category and one tag.

For example:
We have multiple post like: Blanket, Blender, Mixer, Wardrobe

Categories name: Household, Bedroom

Tag names: Kitchen, Bedroom

Accepted result by clicking "Kitchen" link:

- Blender
- Mixer

Accepted result by clicking "Bedroom" link:

- Blanket
- Wardrobe

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking for, but I suspect you just want to be able to link to a specific category or a specific tag? Is this inside a nav menu? Or are you asking how to do this via code? Or have I misunderstood? Your bit about accepted results doesn't make much sense as we know nothing about your website, e.g. is Blender tagged with the tag `kitchen`?

Comment: Thanks @TomJNowell - In short, I want to show post which has tag => "Kitchen", and also category under the =>"Household".  How can do with code?

Comment: Can you give an example with URLs in your question? It's still unclear what you mean to me and I can think of several meanings that aren't the same. E.g. "I want to show post" could mean literally showing the post title and content in the header, or maybe you want to be able to link to a specific post chosen via settings? Or maybe you're trying to put a link in a navigation menu you already have? Maybe you want it to be a link, or maybe you just want text, it's not clear. I also don't understand what you mean by "under the", I can't see your website so visual directions don't make sense

Comment: If it helps, use annotated screenshots, and be specific, don't assume we understand what you mean by "give to" or "under the". You also didn't answer most of the questions I asked in my first comment :(